# Python identity shift matrix

Tags: python, matrix, binary

Is there any *inline* command to generate a shifted identity matrix in python with numpy?

```
A=[ ...
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could use the `k` parameter of [np.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html):

```
import numpy as np

result = np.eye(10, 10, 1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

from the linked documentation:

> k : int, optional Index of the diagonal: 0 (the default) refers to the
>   main diagonal, a positive value refers to an upper diagonal, and a
>   negative value to a lower diagonal.